# MapReduce or Hadoop plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am looking for a plugin in Eclipse that can automate some of the work when creating a MapReduce job using Java.

For example:

- Auto create Mapper - Reducer classes(implementing the interfaces).
- Provide some samples to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Hadoop Eclipse Plug-in](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn):

> The Hadoop Eclipse Plug-in provides tools to ease the experience of
>   Map/Reduce on Hadoop. Among other things, the plug-in provides support
>   to:
>
> - create Mapper, Reducer, Driver classes;
> - browse and interact with distributed file systems;
> - submit jobs and monitor their execution.